# Get key used to change Spaces

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there any way to programatically determine what key is set in System Preferences to change to a specific Space.

This setting is configured in the Expose & Spaces preference, under the Spaces tab. The last drop down box is titled "To switch directly to a space" and you can choose from the control key, the command key, the option key or no key.

This is the value I'd like to programatically determine.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using AppleScript's GUI scripting to programatically open the preferences pane and see what is in the drop down box. An example is [here](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html). To invoke it from Objective-C, check out [Scripting Bridge](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/scriptingbridge.html) if you're using OS 10.5 or later, otherwise there's an older API but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

If you want a solution that doesn't require popping up the System Preferences window and showing all its animations to the user, the actual value is stored somewhere in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`, but the format is not human-readable. You could change the key binding from System Preferences and compare that file before and after. Keep in mind that this may be different between versions of OS X.

Hope this helps, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks for the tips; it all seems a bit indirect and the values returned with these method are not something I can rely being the same in the future. I'll go with asking the user to manually set the key in my apps Preferences